# SilverStripe Dataobject as pages using 2 images

Tags: php, silverstripe, data-objects

I'm trying to develop a tutorial from http://www.ssbits.com that uses Dataobject as pages. Here's the link to it: http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-1-keeping-it-simple

Now in the tutorial (which I've used already in my projects) there's only one image per staff member, I want to associate 2 images per staff member (I've used products instead of staff members), I guess I need to use $has_many relation but when I try it doesn't work properly, it uploads the images but it doesn't associate them with the staff member (product in my case). Here's how I did it:

```
//Relations
static $has_one = array (
   'ProductPage' => 'ProductPage'
);

static $has_many = array (
  'Photo1' => 'Image',
  'Photo2' => 'Image'
);
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks
Mauro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use has_one instead of has_many. you'd use has_many in case you wanted to have 'a bunch of images' but you need 'exactly 2'.

Comment: Thanks that worked like a breeze. So I guess that if I want a bunch of images I'll need an array or another db table for the images?

Comment: in case you're on silverstripe version 2.4, you'd best go with ImageDataObjectManager, as described here: http://doc.silverstripe.org/old/modules:dataobjectmanager (using some 'linking' object for the images) -- i'm not sure yet what's the best way on silverstripe 3.0 though.